# Unable to understand <A HREF> tag and javascript call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, class

I have a php application in which the web page displayed to the user. The page has some links "Edit", "Rename", etc.

When the user clicks on the link a dialogbox prompts. The dialogbox is nothing but a HTML `<div>` form that gets instantly displayed when the user clicks on the "Rename" or "Edit" link.

When I looked at the html source code (i.e. view -> source in Internet Explorer) I found the following Javascript and HTML code

```
<a class="update renameButton" href="javascript:void(0);">Rename</a>
```

I'm unable to understand how the dialogbox gets promted with the above code.

I expected the code to be something like the following:

```
<a class="update" onclick='rename();' href="javascript:void(0);">Rename</a>
```

Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: If it was your own code, you probably would know it

Answer (score 3):

Some JavaScript loaded from a `<script>` element probably [binds an event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) function to the element.

Answer (score 3):

The event handler is most likely bound to the element elsewhere (from an included JavaScript file perhaps). For example:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("update")[0].addEventListener("click", function () {
    // Do something on click of the first `.update` element
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not setup event listeners in html anymore like with `onclick`.
the page registers an event listener to the Object. e.g. with a library like jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

You are absolutely correct! That is very natural to expect such a thing except that there are other ways to bind an event to an object as well.

If you check the JavaScript code on the page I am sure you will find perhaps something that looks like $('a.renameButton').click(function(){}); (if the site is using jQuery) or something similar that binds the onclick event of that particular  tag to perform some specific actions.